# R - Use regex to extract information from a Data Frame

Tags: r, regex, extract

I have thsi Data Frame

```
L1 <- read_csv("L1.csv", col_names=FALSE)
```

Which looks like this:

```
95  CVEGEO=0901500011341<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1341<BR>
96  CVEGEO=0901500010837<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=0837<BR>
97  CVEGEO=0901500010201<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=0201<BR>
98  CVEGEO=0901600011226<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=016<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=1226<BR>
99  CVEGEO=0901500010606<BR>CVE_ENT=09<BR>CVE_MUN=015<BR>CVE_LOC=0001<BR>CVE_AGEB=0606<BR>
```

And I´m trying to obtain the AGEB number. This code works for the last row:

```
AGEBS_L1 <- sub(".*AGEB=(.*)<.*", "\\1", L1)
```

But when I try yo use ´lapply´ to obtain the AGEBS in all of my rowns:

```
AGEBS_L1 <- lapply(L1, sub(".*AGEB=(.*)<.*", "\\1", L1))
```

It doesn´t work. So I´m here hoping for a hint on how to do it.

Comment: `sub(".*AGEB=(.*)<.*", "\\1", L1$V2)` extracts all of them for me. Note that I'm operating on a vector (one column of the frame), whereas your code is attempting to work on the whole frame at once, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: hmm, yep, you are right... now I feel like i should erase these topic

Comment: You aren't the first, but feel free

Comment: BTW: this is a great example of when R does much better with *vectorized* operations. `sub` happens to work on a full vector of strings at a time, whether 2 or 2 million, and it is always faster than trying to iterate over each of the strings manually (within base R, that is). Be on the lookout for doing things whole-vectors-at-a-time, as it can simplify the readability of code and make it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sub(".AGEB=(.)<.*", "\1", L1$V2)` extracts all of them for me. Note that I'm operating on a vector (one column of the frame), whereas your code is attempting to work on the whole frame at once, which does not make sense to me.
                    – r2evans